# Hacking into the Drupal Login

Tags: drupal, authentication

I am very experienced with PHP etc but a Drupal newbie. I would like to know if there is a way I could put in some additional PHP code once a user has logged in to a Drupal site. The reason I need to do this - to update fields in a different database (not the MySQL Drupal DB). I would need to have access to the Drupal site login username and the session cookie generated by drupal. I would be most grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8):

Create a module and implement the hook_user hook to check for a login action.

If your module name is mymodule, then create a function called

```
mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'login') {
    // Perform your task.
  }
}
```

More information on the user hook is here: [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had managed to figure this out  in the mean time. However, I have a follow on question - is there a way I can do any/all of the following from mymodule_user

a. Determine the name of the user logging in/out
b. Determine the session ID for the Drupal session
c. Send back a custom cookie

I'd be most grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the global $user object in the hook_user to get the name and session info.